# Android Firebase push notification not showing

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-notifications

Hey I am trying to send a push notification to my app using Firebase and I am learning from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

when I go in to the firebase notification and send notification it tells me that the state is complete but doesn't send any notifications to my app and I can't figure out why.. I followed this tutorial exactly

here is the code I took from the tutorial:

Config class

```
public class Config {

        public static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";

        public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";
public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";

        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;

        public static final String SHARED_PREF = "ah_firebase";
```

}

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // Saving reg id to shared preferences
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

    // sending reg id to your server
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

MyFirebaseMessagingService class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

}

NotificationUtil class

```
public class NotificationUtils {

private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

        private Context mContext;

        public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    }

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

        public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
    return;

    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
            mContext,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
        } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


        private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .setSound(alarmSound)
    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
    .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
    .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
   .setAutoCancel(true)
   .setContentTitle(title)
   .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
   .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
    .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
    .setContentText(message)
    .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

       public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
       URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
    }

        // Playing notification sound
        public void playNotificationSound() {
    /*try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

    return isInBackground;
    }

public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
        return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

}

MainActivity

```
    txtRegId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
    txtMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);

    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };

    displayFirebaseRegId();


}

private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
    txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
    else
    txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));


    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));
    NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that way not worked for me too try doing this

this into your build.gradle

```
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
```

this into your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service
          android:name=".firebase.FirebaseNotificationService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
```

and create new class called FirebaseNotificationService.java

and this paste this in that file

```
/**

 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at

 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package github.grace5921.TwrpBuilder.firebase;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import github.grace5921.TwrpBuilder.Fragment.BackupFragment;
import github.grace5921.TwrpBuilder.R;

public class FirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackupFragment.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_teamwin_splashlogo)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

you can find my commit on github [here](https://github.com/TwrpBuilder/TwrpBuilder/commit/acfbc609660f23a0ca53971b4b1e42dfbb77c3df) if in case you face any problem

Comment: That's it? I shouldn't update anything on my MainActivity? Just keep my code and add this?

Comment: yes you are making a service which is defined in AndroidManifest so you don't need anything in ManiActivity